# How to insert and retrieve image from SQL Server?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, exception, sql-server-2008-r2

I have written code to insert an Image in SQL server but it throws an exception:

> String or binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated.

Here is my Code for insert image:

```
FileStream imageStream = new FileStream(CvVariables.IMAGE_PATH, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
int fileLangth = (int)imageStream.Length;
byte[] imageInBytes = new byte[fileLangth];
imageStream.Read(imageInBytes, 0, (int)fileLangth);
Cv_Customer_Information addNewCustomer = new Cv_Customer_Information
{
      UserID = this.NewCustomerTextUserName.Text,
      UserImage =new System.Data.Linq.Binary(imageInBytes),
      Date = this.NewCustomerDate.SelectedDate.ToString(),
      Name = this.NewCustomerTextBoxName.Text,
      Phone = this.NewCustomerTextBoxPhone.Text,
      Email = this.NewCustomerTextBoxEmail.Text,
      NationalID = this.NewCustomerTextBoxNationalID.Text,
      Address = this.NewCustomerTextBoxAddress.Text
};
singupDataContext.Cv_Customer_Informations.InsertOnSubmit(addNewCustomer);
singupDataContext.SubmitChanges();
```

I also don`t understand how to retrieve images from SQL Server?

update: I use image Data Type in UserImage field and I am working with WPF

Comment: first part of the question - "String or binary data would be truncated.The statement has been terminated.". This means that your column isn't big enough for the data maybe  it's nvarchar(n) you need to change that to max

Comment: If you're using SQL Server 2008 R2 (as suggested by the tags on this question) you can use [NVARCHAR(MAX)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186939.aspx) column which will [allow up to 2GB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx) of data to be stored within it.

Comment: Those are pretty weird suggestions: this is not character data, it's binary data.  Nvarchar(anything) is just wrong.  There's an 'image' type for this - or varbinary, or filestream if stored on disk.. anything but nvarchar

Comment: There are no long blob, medium blob types in SQL server.  So yes there is a problem - they don't exist.  Varbinary and Image are the appropriate options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, this error means that the data of one of your fields (string or binary) is longer than the database definition of the column in which it will be stored.

This can be for example your username. If the database is a varchar(8) and you try to assign a name of 10 characters, you will get this error.

From the errormessage you cannot deduct what field is causing the error. It can be any string or your Binary data. Crosschek the input with the database definition to find the field/columns that is causing the error.

Solution: provide smaller data or increase the length in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that the column that is holding your image is not big enough to hold the image you are inserting. This means that you will have to increase its length in order to be able to insert the object you want to.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked the code but I remember that I used something similar.

```
Image image;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imageByteArray,0,imageByteArray.Length)) 
{ 
    stream.Write(imageByteArray,0,imageByteArray.Length); 
    image = Image.FromStream(stream,true); 
}
```